# Enable and disable drop down lists

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Enable and disable drop down lists in Excel using VBA]

```
'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'On Error Resume Next
'If Target.Address <> "$O$5" Then Exit Sub
'Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
'    Case "NO"
'        Application.EnableEvents = False
'        Range("Q5,Q20").ClearContents
'        Range("R5,R20").ClearContents
'    Case "YES"
'        'Range("B28,B32").
'        Application.EnableEvents = True
'End Select
'
'exitHandler:
'  Application.EnableEvents = True
'  Exit Sub
'
'End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Address = "$O$5" Then
    Target.Range("O5:08").ClearContents = True
    Sheet9.d
 End If


End Sub
```

I need to be able to enable modified by **Author and Modified by User** drop down lists (created in excel) when 'Yes' is selected in **Make a selection** drop down list and disable **Modified by Author** and **Modified by User** drop down list when No' is selected using VBA code.I have tried everything but don't know how to achieve this. There are no forms used in this project. I would appreciate if you could give me an idea how I can do this through VBA code.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to solve this in your question and explain the problems you are having with it.

Comment: I am not able to find the code for this.

Comment: Have you been deleting rows?  You may have deleted all of your Data Validation cells...

Comment: Data Validation cells are configured manually and are in the right place. If I select on e of those cells the drop down list will show up. But I want disable /enable the ones on the right based upon Yes or No selected from the drop down list on the left (Make a selection). I added my code. Please suggest changes to it so that I can make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have your data validation drop downs set up, you might **just turn off the in-cell drop down** and the **error message** (so the datavalidation stays, even if it is disabled - but it is invisible for the user.

In order to trigger the macro, you use the `Worksheet_Change` event. **This code needs to be placed inside your sheet**, not in a module.

I just assumed that your "Make a selection" range is `O5:O12` and that there is a hidden column between "Make a selection" and "Modified by author"

```
'Triggered when any cell on the sheet is changed
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Check if Target cell in the "Make a selection" range is changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("O5:O12")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            'Dropdown and error message on cells 2 and 3 columns left of "Make a selection" will be enabled
            With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Validation
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
            With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 3).Validation
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
            'Dropdown and error message on cells 2 and 3 columns left of "Make a selection" will be enabled
             With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Validation
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .ShowError = False
            End With
            With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 3).Validation
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .ShowError = False
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Be aware that you need to to have a data validation already set up - otherwise you will receive an error.

Alternatively, you might use `Validation.Delete` to remove your drop down and `Validation.Add` to enable your drop down. But that is more coding.

Comment: That certainly helped. Is there any way I can add a different color (show in the figure)  to the drop down where we have removed the data validation from, so that it appears to the user like it was disabled.

Comment: Yes, sure. The easiest is probably just a conditional formatting (you might use something lik =$Q5="No"). Alternatively, you can add something like Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200) for each of the four cases.

Comment: Interior.ColorIndex or the Interior.Color within the With statement throws an object not supported exception.

Comment: @Ruruboy You cannot put into the same with-statement, it should look something like the `With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
            With .Validation
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
    End With`

Comment: @Ruruboy Sorry for the bad code formatting, I am not sure if that can be done better in the comment section, but I hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: Michael that color changes now thanks. But I have noticed that Make a selection dropdown list gets triggered when I select "No",  but the validation in the dropdown list doesn't clear (still appears) until I mouse out and click on two other cells. The event I am using as above is the Worksheet selection change. Do I need to set another property so that the  worksheet changes immediately after  I  select "Yes" or "No" in the 'Make a selection' drop down list

Comment: @Ruruboy So if I understand correctly, you want to delete the value from the drop down? Just add `.Value = vbNullString` under the line that changes the color.