# Enabling and disabling data validation drop-down lists in vba

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I'm trying to get it so that in a column, when a user picks from three options in a drop-down list, depending on which option they select, the cell to the right either shows another drop-down list, or allows free text entry.

I need the data validation error message to be on by default, so am trying to turn the drop-down and validation error message on/off depending on what they select in the first dropdown.

In my situation, there are three options in column O: "Yes", "No" and "Unverified". If the user selects "Unverified", then there is a drop-down in the cell to the right, and an error message is shown if any other text is entered. If the user selects "Yes" or "No", I want to turn off the drop-down, and not show the error in the cell to the right (so that they can essentially put a free text answer in).

I've googled and used code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59167393/21727127) to get to the below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo ExitSub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("O16:O615")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Unverified" Then
        With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Validation
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
        
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Validation
            .InCellDropdown = False
            .ShowError = False
        End With

    ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
        With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Validation
            .InCellDropdown = False
            .ShowError = False
        End With
    End If

End If

ExitSub:

End Sub
```

This seems to work fine if I select "Unverified" in column O (it doesn't throw an error at least - the validation is set up on the sheet beforehand, so essentially I'm looking for "no change" in this case).

However, if I select "Yes" or "No", then I get a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error", and Debug takes me to ".InCellDropdown = False" in the relevant section (depending on if I pick "Yes" or "No").

Would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Works for me, as long as the validation is already set up in Col P.  You do need to account for the case where a user initially selects Yes/No and enters a value in P, but then changes O to "unverified", potentially leaving an invalid value in P.

Comment: Thank you for trying it - Good point about changing the value in O after entering one in P, I'll have to think about that.

I've tried running this in a completely new workbook, and I now get the error message on all three options, but highlighting ".ShowError = False" instead of ".InCellDropdown = False".  I am so very confused.

Comment: Is there a list validation applied to P16:P615 ?

Comment: There is - but you asking just prompted me to try with a direct reference for the list validation, rather than how I had previously set it up with the list dependent on what was selected in column O (=INDIRECT(O16)). With the direct list reference, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, as long as the validation is already set up in Col P.

You do need to account for the case where a user initially selects Yes/No and enters a value in P, but then changes O to "unverified", potentially leaving an invalid value in P.

Code could be streamlined a bit:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("O16:O615")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
        .InCellDropdown = (Target.Value = "Unverified")
        .ShowError = .InCellDropdown
    End With
End Sub
```